# How do I install python-wxgtk3.0 on Parrot-sec (pretty much debian)?

Tags: python, installation, debian-based

Trying apt(-get) doesn't work, pip doesn't work and downloading the .deb package itself doesn't work either so here we are. I'll post any error messages deemed necessary, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone runs into trouble with this, I managed to solve this by adding `deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian stretch main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` then doing `sudo apt update` and finally `sudo apt install python-wxgtk3.0`